# Firing Mouseout Event depends on Window Size

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, jsfiddle, mouseout

I want to draw on a 3D-transformed canvas, but have some weird problems with the mouseout event in Chrome.

When I set the JSFiddle window size to 2100px, the mouseout event works as excepted.

[image]

However, when I set the window size to 1900px, the mouse event triggers approximately at the red line.

[image]

This is really weird, since the JSFiddle window size determines if the mouse out event is triggered correctly.

Until here the mouse out event is triggered correctly in Firefox and Edge, but doesn't work correctly in Chrome! In addition, we saw some weird behaviour when playing around with the scrolling position (e.g. by adding some `<br>`'s and scrolling affects the mouse out event position), window sizes (see images above) or the width of the canvas (e.g. setting the canvas width to 200 triggers the mouse out event correctly).

Is there anyone who can help me solving this bug, such that the browser fires the mouseout event correctly independent of the window size or scroll position?

Code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/90nr8sdy/60/)

Demo: [YouTube](https://youtu.be/fXY1Vg9kgHk)

Snippet of code in fiddle:

```js
$(".dynamic-drawing-canvas").on("mouseout", function(e) {
  console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY)
})
```

```css
#container {
  pointer-events: none;
  margin-left: 400px;
}

.dynamic-drawing-canvas {
  pointer-events: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <canvas class="dynamic-drawing-canvas" width="1200" height="300" style="
    transform: matrix3d(1.0303, 0.00317459, 0, 2.13211e-05, -0.68458, -0.165542, 0, -0.00111181, 0, 0, 1, 0, -34.7412, 264.118, 0, 1);
    transform-origin: left top;
"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this locally or on CodePen. To ensure this issue is not with JSFiddle platform itself, could you please post a CodePen link demonstrating the same issue?

Comment: Sure: https://codepen.io/wuiuw/pen/QWggvbM
Same issue: Canvas has enough space (= canvas is completely visible + has some space on the left and right) => works; Canvas is completely visible but the window width is minimal => Event fires at wrong position

Comment: This works on firefox, doesn't work on chrome/edge. I think it might be the way they handle the transform, not sure where's the problem's at yet tho

Comment: @wuiwuiwui How are you going about resizing your window? When I resize your CodePen window in Chrome, the trapezoid does not scale but simply gets cropped, at which point I scroll to see it's hidden edges. The event still seems to fire at the correct edge points for me.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in any browser (macOS)

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell Maybe this helps: https://youtu.be/fXY1Vg9kgHk

Comment: I found out that I can't reproduce it on my MacBook either. However, when I connect my  wide screen (also used in the YouTube Video) to the same MacBook, the bug appears! But using a different screen shouldn't really affect a listener...

Comment: Actually I got mislead by my canary browser (which had a different window size than my stable one). The issue is still not fixed, and running a bisect, I found that it has always been there (at least since M53). And of course webkit also has the same bug...

Comment: So since there is no workaround, probably the best thing to do is to report it to Google and wait?

Comment: Yes @wuiwuiwui you could do that :) But don't expect a bug fix anytime soon

Comment: I created a new fiddle that I think is easier to reproduce the bug using CSS :hover (https://jsfiddle.net/2sgu0a6q/2/), it is not related to the canvas element, it's related to CSS function matrix3d, I did not find a solution, but if you change the values `-0.68458, -0.165542, 0, -0.00111181` that represents the second line of the matrix, you should see the bug changing the behavior and fixing it, maybe a workaround should be limit these values if you can.

Comment: does the same behaviour happen when the browser window is maximized?

Comment: @Jabbar Yes, same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running into an issue with the container of the canvas.

Some notes on what is happening:
The canvas is generated at 1200px and 300px for width/height using the properties in the markup: `width="1200" height="300"` You can override this in the `<canvas>` tag directly or with JavaScript.
Why CSS resize has issues: What the CSS does is to resize the existing canvas to a new size. When a typical/most HTML component is resized the browser handles this fine. The difference is `<canvas>` is a collection of pixels. When you change with CSS these pixels become altered (stretched out or shrink down) and the image on the canvas gets a different look. Note also that the blank canvas is also stretched so drawing to it has challenges and might/does not work as expected.

Here I adjust your canvas to fit the container using JavaScript on these properties but really only for an example - your size will vary.

I added some borders so you can see things - I put some logs in place to show where it changes and the `mouseout` fires since it now fits inside the container - I scaled it to fit using the `1.1` and moved the style to the CSS so I could add comments from before to after.

```js
console.clear();
let canvas = document.getElementById("c");

let width = canvas.width;
let height = canvas.height;
console.log("CW:", width, "CH:", height);
let rect = canvas.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
canvas.width = rect.width;
canvas.height = rect.height;

width = canvas.width;
height = canvas.height;
let r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
let ctop = r.top;
let cleft = r.left;
console.log("T:", ctop, "L:", cleft, "W:", width, "H:", height);
$(".dynamic-drawing-canvas")
  .on("mouseout", function(e) {
    // console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    console.log("Screen X/Y:", e.screenX, e.screenY, "Client X/Y:", e.clientX, e.clientY);
    console.log("X:", e.screenX - e.clientX);
    console.log("Y:", e.screenY - e.clientY);
  });
```

```css
#container {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid red 3px;
}

.dynamic-drawing-canvas {
  pointer-events: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  object-fit: none;
  object-position: top left;
  transform-origin: left top;
  /* pulled out of markup, alter for 2.13211e-5 */
  /*
  transform: matrix3d(
  1.0303, 0.00317459, 0, 0.0000213211,
  -0.68458, -0.165542, 0, -0.00111181,
  0, 0, 1, 0,
  -34.7412, 264.118, 0, 1
  ); 
  THEN adjusted the 
      following transformations:
         0, 30, 0, 1.1
        Translates every X point by 0px
        Translates every Y point by 30px
        Translates every Z point by 0
        Scales down by 10%
*/
  transform: matrix3d(1.0303, 0.00317459, 0, 0.0000213211, 0.68458, 0.165542, 0, 0.00111181, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 30, 0, 1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="c" class="dynamic-drawing-canvas" width="1200" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. You hide the problem, you didn't fix it :) `or factor that into some creative CSS`, that's actually what he's looking for in an answer imho

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy - Matter of opinion - if the image exceeds the canvas border/size what should happen? Note CSS in this case is NOT the answer.  I will add a bit more detail in the answer to add more clarity